# Event scheduler (cronjob) in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

How can I set an event scheduler in `Mongodb`?

I will create an event that every 4 hours calculate fields (SUM|COUNT) in the collection then save it.

What is the Best Solution to arrive at this?
thanks:)

Comment: This seems like a good fit for my package called [mongodb-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-cron).

Comment: You can emulate a cronjob with MongoDB 3.6, using Change Streams and TTL - code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49389459/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-capture-ttl-events-with-change-stream-to-emulate-a-sc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of version 3.2, MongoDB has no built-in cronjob system (with the exception of the TTL index auto-delete jobs, but these won't help you to solve this problem).

That means you will have to use an external tool to start the mongo shell with your query as a parameter to it. There are countless tools available for this. Some build into all common operating systems out-of-the box and some in form of 3rd party tools. There are far too many options to list; which is the best depends on your IT infrastructure and what your system administrators prefer.

Comment: It's Very Bad:( because  out-of-the box Applications maybe no be Stable!

Comment: @M.Eskandari The OS scheduling systems are very reliable indeed.  They've been around a *long* time and have been well proven.

Comment: @M.Eskandari Scheduling cronjobs is a topic for system administrators to worry about. We are software developers, so this is not our area of expertise. If you would like to talk to system administrators, try https://serverfault.com

Comment: Dear @Philipp , Events is part of database's , in mysql I write Events `CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT...` like it and I think Stackoverflow is better place for this Question! I known Serverfault too, This Comment is better for inside my Question not this Answer :)))) ,Thanks

Comment: @M.Eskandari Events might be part of MySQL and some other relational databases, but they are certainly not a part of MongoDB.

Comment: I made a light NPM package https://github.com/xpepermint/mongodb-cron which can help. I've been using it in a clustered environment for a long time and I'm very happy with the results.

Answer (score 1):

Try [MongoDB Cron](https://github.com/xpepermint/mongodb-cron) package. It's a simple API for scheduling tasks and running recurring jobs on MongoDB collections. Any collection can be converted into a job queue or crontab list.

Comment: Probably a good idea to indicate that you are the creator of this package : ]