# Automating daily import task in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Currently, I am exploring MongoDB and I have a very basic scenario related to automating an import job in MongoDB. I have a text file placed daily at a particular location(FTP) and I need to import .txt file into MongoDB on a daily basis. My question is what is the mechanism available in MongoDB to do this without manually doing this. Is there any kind of job scheduler available in MongoDB?

Comment: MongoDB is a "database". It has no "job scheduler". There are too many ways of doing this and therefore your question is too broad. Pick a language implementation and try something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event scheduler (cronjob) in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291654/event-scheduler-cronjob-in-mongodb)