# how can i Decrement a field in mongodb database daily

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, typescript, mlab

I'm trying to build an angular2 application using mean stack architecture,I got a field Remaining days in my database mongodb,I want that field decrement 1 every day.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this stackoverflow link :

[Event scheduler (cronjob) in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291654/event-scheduler-cronjob-in-mongodb)

You might have to write an external job scheduler and update the field in  mongodb.