# MongoDB: is it possible to capture TTL events with Change Stream to emulate a scheduler (cronjob)?

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and I'm looking for a way to do the following:

I have a collection of a number of available "things" to be used.
The user can "save" a "thing" and decrement the number of available things. 
But he has a time to use it before it expires. 
If it expires, the thing has to go back to the collection, incrementing it again.

It would be ideal if there was a way to monitor "expiring dates" in Mongo. But in my searches I've only found a TTL (time to live) for automatically deleting entire documents.

However, what I need is the "event" of the expiration... Than I was wondering if it would be possible to capture this event with Change Streams. Then I could use the event to increment "things" again.

Is it possible or not? Or would there be a better way of doing what I want?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#delete-operations Expired documents do not magically disappear by its own. It is normal regular `delete` operation.

Comment: thanks Alex... so, in principle, it seems to be possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to use Change Streams and TTL to emulate a cronjob.

But, basically, anytime I need to schedule an "event" for a document, when I'm creating the document I also create an event document in parallel. This event document will have as its _id the same id of the first document.

Also, for this event document I will set a TTL.

When the TTL expires I will capture its "delete" change with Change Streams. And then I'll use the documentKey of the change (since it's the same id as the document I want to trigger) to find the target document in the first collection, and do anything I want with the document.

I'm using Node.js with Express and Mongoose to access MongoDB.
Here is the relevant part to be added in the App.js:

```
const { ReplSet } = require('mongodb-topology-manager');

run().catch(error => console.error(error));

async function run() {
    console.log(new Date(), 'start');
    const bind_ip = 'localhost';
    // Starts a 3-node replica set on ports 31000, 31001, 31002, replica set
    // name is "rs0".
    const replSet = new ReplSet('mongod', [
        { options: { port: 31000, dbpath: `${__dirname}/data/db/31000`, bind_ip } },
        { options: { port: 31001, dbpath: `${__dirname}/data/db/31001`, bind_ip } },
        { options: { port: 31002, dbpath: `${__dirname}/data/db/31002`, bind_ip } }
    ], { replSet: 'rs0' });

    // Initialize the replica set
    await replSet.purge();
    await replSet.start();
    console.log(new Date(), 'Replica set started...');

    // Connect to the replica set
    const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:31000,localhost:31001,localhost:31002/' + 'test?replicaSet=rs0';
    await mongoose.connect(uri);
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function () {
        console.log("Connected correctly to server");
    });

    // To work around "MongoError: cannot open $changeStream for non-existent database: test" for this example
    await mongoose.connection.createCollection('test');

    // *** we will add our scheduler here *** //

    var Item = require('./models/item');
    var ItemExpiredEvent = require('./models/scheduledWithin');
    
    let deleteOps = {
      $match: {
          operationType: "delete" 
      }
    };

    ItemExpiredEvent.watch([deleteOps]).
        on('change', data => {
            // *** treat the event here *** //
            console.log(new Date(), data.documentKey);
            Item.findById(data.documentKey, function(err, item) {
                console.log(item);
            });
        });

    // The TTL set in ItemExpiredEvent will trigger the change stream handler above
    console.log(new Date(), 'Inserting item');
    Item.create({foo:"foo", bar: "bar"}, function(err, cupom) {
        ItemExpiredEvent.create({_id : item._id}, function(err, event) {
            if (err) console.log("error: " + err);
            console.log('event inserted');
        });
    });

}
```

And here is the code for model/ScheduledWithin:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ScheduledWithin = new Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
}, {timestamps: true}); 
// timestamps: true will automatically create a "createdAt" Date field

ScheduledWithin.index({createdAt: 1}, {expireAfterSeconds: 90});

module.exports = mongoose.model('ScheduledWithin', ScheduledWithin);
```

Comment: What happens if this is running like a kubernates pods with 2 or 3 nodes. The changed stream will be notified by all the pod instances and cause collision ???

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the detailed code.

I have two partial alternatives, just to give some ideas.

1.
Given we at least get the **_id** back, if you only need a specific key from your deleted document, you can manually specify **_id** when you create it and you'll at least have this information.

2. (mongodb 4.0)
   A bit more involved, this method is to take advantage of the **oplog history** and open a watch stream at the moment of creation (if you can calculate it), via the **startAtOperationTime** option.

You'll need to check how far back your **oplog history** goes, to see if you can use this method:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.printReplicationInfo/#rs.printReplicationInfo

Note: I'm using the mongodb library, not mongoose

```
// https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/timestamp.html
const { Timestamp } = require('mongodb');

const MAX_TIME_SPENT_SINCE_CREATION = 1000 * 60 * 10; // 10mn, depends on your situation

const cursor = db.collection('items')
  .watch([{
    $match: {
      operationType: 'delete'
    }
  }]);

cursor.on('change', function(change) {
  // create another cursor, back in time
  const subCursor = db.collection('items')
    .watch([{
      $match: {
        operationType: 'insert'
      }
    }], {
      fullDocument        : 'updateLookup',
      startAtOperationTime: Timestamp.fromString(change.clusterTime - MAX_TIME_SPENT_SINCE_CREATION)
    });

  subCursor.on('change', function(creationChange) {
    // filter the insert event, until we find the creation event for our document
    if (creationChange.documentKey._id === change.documentKey._id) {
      console.log('item', JSON.stringify(creationChange.fullDocument, false, 2));
      subCursor.close();
    }
  });
});
```