# How to keep the Lived documents in MongoDB as per the TTL index?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

I know that the TTL index in MongoDB set a time to live for its documents. When they live for the specified time then those documents gets deleted. So what if I want to archive those documents without losing them. is there any way to do it?
I am sorry If I asked it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [change stream](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) to capture documents inserted and archive them somewhere. See also this answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49389459/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-capture-ttl-events-with-change-stream-to-emulate-a-sc).

Answer (score 0):

At the start you have a document with "column" (timestamp) that is in the TTL index. To prevent its deletion, you can move that timestamp to the future, or remove that "column" from the document.