# How I can set dynamic mongoose schema property when e.g expired_at property is less than Date.now?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have `created_at` date, `duration` by minutes set by admin and `expires_at` properties, I have written a logic to calculate the `expires_at` property and its working fine, also I need to set `expired` as a boolean to set to `true` if now date is greater than  `expires_at` I have written a function and its working but I don't know if mongoose can trigger it or when?

so the question is how can I update `expired` property to `true` when current time is passed the `expires_at` time ?

```
const PollSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  question: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  options: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
  expires_at: {
    type: Date,
  },
  expired: {
    type: Boolean,  
    default: false // how I can update this value to true when now > expires_at;
  },
  duration: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
});

PollSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  const poll = this;
  poll.expired = expired(poll);
  next();
});
PollSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  const poll = this;
  var now = new Date();
  poll.expires_at = now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + poll.duration);
  next();
});

// I am triggering this function on save, but I think it should be triggered when now > poll.expires_at;
  
PollSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  const poll = this;
  const now = new Date();
  poll.expired = now > poll.expires_at;
  next();
});
```

Comment: What is your question? using the pre middleware for save, the code will run for the document when it's created or updated

Comment: Hi, the question is how can I update `expired` property to `true` when current time is passed the `expires_at` time ?

Comment: You want it to be done automatically ritght? Not only when the document is updated right? You will have to use some external stuff to do that, cron jobs for example

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned that I don't want to make any scheduler or logic on the controller side!

Comment: Hmmm i see, there is not way to automatically update records in mongodb without an external scheduler (unless  using cron expressions in Atlas), take a loot at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291654/event-scheduler-cronjob-in-mongodb